# python XML element removal error

Tags: python, xml

I read an tree from a file as a string and remove from it namespaces.

```
with open(pathArxmlFileName, 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read();
data = re.sub(' xmlns="[^"]+"', '', data, count=1)
self.root = ET.fromstring(data);        
self.tree =  ET.ElementTree(self.root)
```

I want to remove an XML elemet from this tree

I tried:

```
for EL in self.root.iter('tagString'):
    self.root.remove(EL);
```

This find EL elements but when I call remove() function gives error:

```
   self._children.remove(element)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Please help me , i dont know what to do :(

Ps:Modification of the tree by modifying an element value works

Comment: Post minimal XML example that still demonstrate the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this error is being thrown because you are trying to remove elements with 'tagString' as if they were immediate children of your root element. If the 'tagString' elements are nested farther inside of the tree, trying to remove them using the root element will cause the error you are seeing.

Example XML:

```
<RootElement>
  <Child>
    <tagString/>
  </Child>
</RootElement>
```

So basically you end up calling:

```
root.remove(EL)
```

where root is "RootElement" and EL is "tagString".

The error is thrown because <tagString> isn't the immediate child of <RootElement>!

So if you are going to use ElementTree, you have to instead do something like:

```
for EL in self.root.iter():
    for child in list(EL):
        if child.tag == "tagString":
            EL.remove(child)
```

This will iterate through every element in the tree. It will check if any children contain the tag string you are looking for, and if any are found, it will delete them using the appopriate parent reference, not the root element.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
for EL in self.root.iter('tag1'):
    if parameterFound == True:
        break;
    for numValue in EL.findall('tag2'):#finds only direct childrens
        [name, val]=self.__getParameterNameAndValue(numValue);
        if name == paramNameToDel:
            parameterFound = True;
            EL.remove(numValue);
            break;
    for numValue in EL.findall('tag3'):#finds only direct childrens
        [name, val]=self.__getParameterNameAndValue(numValue);
        if name == paramNameToDel:
            parameterFound = True;
            EL.remove(numValue);
            break;
return parameterFound
```